# Trying to remove the header between combined ascii files in python

Tags: python, header, ascii

I am a compelete newbie to python and i was asked to combine a batch of ascii files. Each of these files are uploaded by the user and they all have a header at the top and bottom. The output (combined) file needs to have just a header at the top and bottom (all headers between the combined files need to be removed).

in my code below you will see that I managed to combine them together but I cannot figure out how to remove the headers in betwee the combined files.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from  tkinter import  filedialog 
ASCII_Data_Files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(filetypes = [('ASC Files', '*.asc'),('All Files', '*.*')]) 
   
Recombined_File = r"D:\\desktop\\try_data\\wip\\Recombined_File.asc"

with open(Recombined_File, 'w') as Output_file: 
    Header = False 
    
    for i in range(len(ASCII_Data_Files)):
        
        Single_ASCII = ASCII_Data_Files[i]  #single ASCII is a single element or single file in the selected files 
        
        with open (Single_ASCII, 'r') as ASCII_file:
            
            Lines = ASCII_file.readlines()
            
            for ASCII_line in Lines:
                
                if Header == False:
                    
                  Output_file.write(ASCII_line)
                Header == False 
        Header == True
```

Comment: can you provide an example of your files?, are they csv or fix column width?

Comment: You may want to review your indentation. As shown, I don't think you'll get the desired behaviour. Think about where/when Header is set to True

Comment: It is a fixed column width, not csv ! I am able to put them together with this code that i provided, i just do not know how to remove the headers.